# Firefox can't open download folder

Tags: 22.04, firefox, snap, dolphin

I think that the firefox snap confinement issue that has plagued many is causing this problem, but I'm not sure.  My problem is that when I download a file, I typically will click on the "Open Folder" button next to the file so I can browse to it in my file explorer (using KDE dolphin).  But instead, when I click the folder, simply nothing happens.

In another instance, if a webpage needs to upload a file, the "Browse" button would usually open a file selection dialog.  However, in my case, the button is simply unresponsive.  This is the case on pretty much every web page I visit.

Everything I've read about this issue says that it's due to strict confinement of the firefox snap package, and to use the [home interface](https://snapcraft.io/docs/home-interface) to access files in my home directory and the [removeable media](https://snapcraft.io/docs/removable-media-interface) interface for mounted filesystems.

I've done that.  It appeared to be that way by default.  I also tried using --classic flag during snap installation to remove confinement, but that was ignored.

This is enormously frustrating, and I am in disbelief that this issue has been allowed to persist for so long.  My current work-around is to spin up a windows VM and do my file mashing there.  Surely this isn't what the rest of the ubuntu community is doing.

Kubuntu 22.04, updates automatically applied regularly

EDIT:  Here are details about my firefox snap:

```
$ snap connections firefox 
Interface                 Plug                            Slot                             Notes
audio-playback            firefox:audio-playback          :audio-playback                  -
audio-record              firefox:audio-record            :audio-record                    -
avahi-observe             firefox:avahi-observe           :avahi-observe                   -
browser-support           firefox:browser-sandbox         :browser-support                 -
camera                    firefox:camera                  :camera                          -
content[gnome-3-38-2004]  firefox:gnome-3-38-2004         gnome-3-38-2004:gnome-3-38-2004  -
content[gtk-3-themes]     firefox:gtk-3-themes            gtk-common-themes:gtk-3-themes   -
content[icon-themes]      firefox:icon-themes             gtk-common-themes:icon-themes    -
content[sound-themes]     firefox:sound-themes            gtk-common-themes:sound-themes   -
cups-control              firefox:cups-control            -                                -
dbus                      -                               firefox:dbus-daemon              -
desktop                   firefox:desktop                 :desktop                         -
desktop-legacy            firefox:desktop-legacy          :desktop-legacy                  -
gsettings                 firefox:gsettings               :gsettings                       -
hardware-observe          firefox:hardware-observe        :hardware-observe                -
home                      firefox:home                    :home                            -
joystick                  firefox:joystick                :joystick                        -
mount-control             firefox:host-hunspell           :mount-control                   -
mpris                     -                               firefox:mpris                    -
network                   firefox:network                 :network                         -
network-bind              firefox:network-bind            :network-bind                    -
network-observe           firefox:network-observe         -                                -
opengl                    firefox:opengl                  :opengl                          -
personal-files            firefox:dot-mozilla-firefox     :personal-files                  -
removable-media           firefox:removable-media         :removable-media                 -
screen-inhibit-control    firefox:screen-inhibit-control  :screen-inhibit-control          -
system-files              firefox:etc-firefox             :system-files                    -
system-packages-doc       firefox:system-packages-doc     :system-packages-doc             -
u2f-devices               firefox:u2f-devices             :u2f-devices                     -
unity7                    firefox:unity7                  :unity7                          -
upower-observe            firefox:upower-observe          :upower-observe                  -
wayland                   firefox:wayland                 :wayland                         -
x11                       firefox:x11                     :x11                             -
```

```
$ snap info  firefox
name:      firefox
summary:   Mozilla Firefox web browser
publisher: Mozilla✓
store-url: https://snapcraft.io/firefox
contact:   https://support.mozilla.org/kb/file-bug-report-or-feature-request-mozilla
license:   unset
description: |
  Firefox is a powerful, extensible web browser with support for modern web application
  technologies.
commands:
  - firefox
  - firefox.geckodriver
snap-id:      3wdHCAVyZEmYsCMFDE9qt92UV8rC8Wdk
tracking:     latest/stable
refresh-date: today at 15:33 EDT
channels:
  latest/stable:    113.0.2-1     2023-05-23 (2710) 254MB -
  latest/candidate: 114.0-3       2023-06-02 (2744) 256MB -
  latest/beta:      114.0b9-1     2023-05-26 (2724) 255MB -
  latest/edge:      115.0a1       2023-05-31 (2742) 262MB -
  esr/stable:       102.11.0esr-2 2023-05-09 (2642) 186MB -
  esr/candidate:    102.12.0esr-1 2023-05-29 (2735) 186MB -
  esr/beta:         ↑                                     
  esr/edge:         ↑                                     
installed:          113.0.2-1                (2710) 254MB -
```

Comment: I wish I could help, but you've provided no details. Please read  https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask and https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting

Comment: @waltinator:  you're right, I should have included details about the snap.  I've edited the question.  Please let me know if you think there are other details I should add.

Comment: What is `apt list --installed|grep -- -portal`?

Comment: @nteodosio:  It gives no output.  What package are you looking for in that command?

Comment: xdg-desktop-portal-gtk/mantic,now 1.14.1-1 amd64  [installiert]
xdg-desktop-portal/mantic,now 1.16.0-2ubuntu1 amd64  [installiert]

Comment: I am experiencing the same issue with my firefox 114.0.1 (64-bit) canonical 002-1.0 in ubuntu 22.04